# Hotkey to start and stop an application?

Tags: macos

I am using [chunkwm](https://github.com/koekeishiya/chunkwm) for managing windows. How can I start/stop it with a hot key? Currently, I start it in a terminal window. To close chunkwm, I "Ctr-C" in the terminal. I would really like to have a hotkey to toggle between chunkwm on and off.

Comment: Take a look at the guide: http://hde-advent-2017.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/12/24/000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start and stop it from any app by creating a Service in Automator. First, open Automator, then create a Service in the next dialog. To launch an application, drag the `Run Shell Script` command into the workflow. In the text box that then appears, type the Unix command you normally use to launch ChunkWM. Save this file and pick a memorable name. For quitting the application, do the same thing, but with a command for quitting the application. Save this as well.

Now go to System Preferences > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Services` > Scroll to `General`. After finding the services you saved earlier, click the `Add Shortcut` button and create shortcuts for each one. (There will need to be 2 different shortcuts; using 1 shortcut requires more advanced Automator coding.)